# Updateable local notification in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

How to show a persistent local notification which updates every second in Flutter? An example of local notification that I am trying to emulate is timer notification of clock app.

I tried using flutter_local_notifications package. One can prediocally update the notification if same notification_id is sent but it acts like new notification is sent every interval which is not good user experience for the use.
[image]